# How to prevent to process same look alike frame again and again

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning

Please anyone help me, I am trying ANPR(for my backyard) for that i am using wpod-net for plate detection/recognition and for OCR using my own trained model, for that i am sending continuous frames in queue/loop (e.g. 2 fps) from live CCTV Feed, so suppose any vehicle is stop somewhere or moving slowly, then system will send same vehicle image too many times and i'll do ANPR for same vehicle again and again, is there any way so that i can prevent processing such image for same vehicle image only once

Comment: Hi, not sure if this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56759785/how-to-maintain-constant-fps-when-grabbing-frames-with-opencv-and-python