# python how to save videos by different names?

Tags: python, video, stream, opencv

My aim is recording stream and saving that stream into folders. The problem is, I have to save every 5 seconds long of stream into different folders. I mean for a 30 seconds long stream, there should be 6 folders. My code is working but I can't measure the seconds correctly, I divided the frames (a) into fps. But it did not give the correct result. Also I cannot save videos into different folders by using different names. I have to give different names but I don't know how to do it.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, time
import os

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
frame_width = int(cap.get(3))
frame_height = int(cap.get(4))

out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M','J','P','G'), 10, (frame_width,frame_height))
a=0
n=0
while(cap.isOpened()):
    a=a+1
    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    sec = a / fps
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    n=n+1

    if ret==True:
        if sec%5==0:
            out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi2', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 10,
                                  (frame_width, frame_height))
        else:
            out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    else:
        break

print(a)
print('fps= '+str(fps))
print('second= '+str(sec))
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55411718/6218543

Answer (score 0):

You can't measure seconds correctly because your script takes time to execute and since python is a relatively slow programming language, the time needed to execute your code is enough to cause a significant delay if you are dealing with libraries. Try importing *datetime* module and measuring time with it

```
import datetime


time_to_wait = datetime.timedelta(seconds=5)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    last = datetime.datetime.now()
    # do your stuff
    if ret==True:
       if datetime.datetime.now() - last >= time_to_wait:
           last = datetime.datetime.now()
           # do your stuff
```

regarding your naming issue I have no sure solution, but you could try using classes and lists, but I'm not sure

Comment: so what should I write to if sec%5==0 section?

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'datetime.datetime' and 'int'

Comment: There is no operand % and there is no type int in 'if datetime.datetime.now() - last >= time_to_wait:'. be sure to write it correctly

Comment: replace 'if sec%5==0' with 'if datetime.datetime.now() - last >= time_to_wait:'